# Как правильно прописать роуты для работы с PSQL через OpenVpn

Tags: маршрутизация, openvpn, psql

Настоен сервер OpenVpn.
При подключении клиент получает адресс из сети `10.7.0.0/24`
Нужно соединиться с БД постгрес, находящемся на удаленном сервере: `10.20.30.40`
Настройки на клиенте, после подключения к VPN:

```
tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.7.0.6  P-t-P:10.7.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

$ ip route 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp1s0  proto static  metric 600 
10.7.0.1 via 10.7.0.5 dev tun1 
10.7.0.5 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.7.0.6 
10.20.30.0/24 via 10.7.0.5 dev tun1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.43.204  metric 600
```

Тоесть все обращения к `10.20.30.40` уходят в туннель.
Дальше само подключение к базе:
`psql -p 1234 -h 10.20.30.40 -U ubuntu test_BD`
Не работает.
Если захожу через VPN на `10.7.0.1` и оттуда выполняю ту же команду, то все открывается - т.е. там уже все дальше уходит корректно.
Где может быть проблема?

Comment: Либо сервер опенвпн не пускает клиентов дальше гулять по сети, либо   в pg_hba.conf чего-то не хватает. Либо одно из двух.

Comment: Sergey, если бы сервер не пускал гулять по сети трафик, то логично было бы предположить, что я не мог бы выполнить psql с любого айпишника из `10.7.0.0/24`. Сейчас же с хоста `10.7.0.1` - команда выполняется, как я и написал. По pg_hba.conf - не могли бы поподробнее описать в ответе, где там может быть затык?

Comment: Либо на выходе из тоннеля нет NAT и при этом на машинке с postgresql нет маршрута, куда возвращать пакеты. Т.е. syn прилетает, ask - улетает не туда. Ну, насколько я схему понял.

Comment: У хвоста 10.7.0.1 что нет другого адреса? А как же он тогда выступает в роли сервера/маршрутизатора опенвпн? С одной стороны 10.7.0.1, с другой 10.20.30.xyz. Так ведь?

Comment: В pg_hba.conf написано каких клиентов postgres пускает, а каким фигвам рисует.  Если в принципе из сети к нему подключаетесь, то этот файл должен быть знаком. Ведь по умолчанию допускает подключения только с localhost. Найдите это файл, откройте в блокноте. Всё станет ясно.